# update while and php

Tags: php, sqlite

Friends, I show the field name as the value 1 of the database and the value as the result of the field, but I can not raise it to save the value of the field.

```
 $result = $db->query($query);

   while($rowID = $result->fetchArray() ){
   echo
   " <label class=\"control-label \" for=\"text\">
        ".$row['value1'] ."
      </label>
      <input class=\"form-control\" value=".$rowID['value2'] ." id=\"\" name=".$rowID['id']." type=\"text\"/>

     </div>";
   }

if( isset($_POST['submit_data']) ){

      $ret1 = $db->query($query);
      while($rowID = $ret1->fetchArray())
       {        

        $query = "UPDATE table set value2 ='" . $_POST[$rowID['id']] . "' WHERE id='" . $rowID['id'] . "'";


            }

        if( $db->exec($query) ){
            $message = "Data is updated successfully.";
        }else{
            $message = "Sorry, Data is not updated.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're showing value1, and storing value2.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com - Learn about SQL injection. Your script is at a very high risk and your database can be hacked in a few seconds!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last generated value in while loop will be value of $query. you should execute query at same time.

```
if( isset($_POST['submit_data']) ){

  $ret1 = $db->query($query);
  while($rowID = $ret1->fetchArray())
   {        

       $query = "UPDATE table set value2 ='" . $_POST[$rowID['id']] . "' WHERE id='" . $rowID['id'] . "'";
       if( $db->exec($query) ){
           $message = "Data is updated successfully.";
       }else{
           $message = "Sorry, Data is not updated.";
       }

    }


}
```